# How to create educational linear algebra animations?

Tags: undergraduate-education, linear-algebra

I'm looking to create animations for a linear algebra course. I need things like writing and changing equations, including matrices, plotting of 2- and 3-dimensional axes with points, vectors, lines and planes, and so on. The intention is to incorporate the animations into a separate video, to demonstrate and visualize what's being said.

How can I go about creating such animations? I'm ideally looking for a free solution.

I'm aware of 3Blue1Brown's youtube channel and vPython package, but I'm looking for other options. Mostly because I don't like working with vPython.

Comment: geogebra does a lot if you are willing to invest the time.

Comment: MathBox could be useful, but I know basically nothing about it so I am only commenting instead of answering.

Answer (score 2):

As an example (I encourage the commenters to make their comments answers), one could use the technology used in [Activity 4.1.2 of Austin's linear algebra](http://merganser.math.gvsu.edu/david/linear.algebra/ula/ula/sec-eigen-intro.html), which makes some reasonable extensive use of javascript.  You can see a bunch of examples together [in the PreTeXt sample article](https://pretextbook.org/examples/sample-article/html/section-interactive-authored.html#interactive-html5-canvas) and how to make them in [the code that goes with it](https://github.com/rbeezer/mathbook/tree/dev/examples/sample-article/code/austin).

Answer (score 0):

You may find some useful things already exist at
https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/
but it's not at all clear to me what the copyright situation is for using them for videos.